# Instagram API - User photos

Tags: instagram, photo

Does anyone know can I get photos from Instagram user without using access token.
It doesn't make sense that I see photos on [http://instagram.com/{user}](http://instagram.com/%7Buser%7D) but can not  get them using Instagram API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I don't believe this is possible using their api.

From instagram's documentation: (http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

> Authenticated requests require an access_token. ...  We only require authentication in cases where your application is making requests on behalf of a user (commenting, liking, **browsing a user’s feed**, etc.).

You might be able to work out some kind of hack. Here's a php implementation using followgram.me http://www.barattalo.it/2011/08/18/how-to-use-instagr-am-photos/

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I am not sure but I think followgram.me uses access token to get user instagram photos. After it expire I guess followgram will not be able to get my latest photos.

Comment: "browsing a user’s feed" is not the same as the photos the user posts themselves. For most situations, you only need the `client_id`

Comment: This is not the correct answer as has been stated.  Javier and dayuloli has the correct answer below

Answer (score 2):

to get the photos You don't need to use the access_token.
just call:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent?callback=&client_id={client_id}
```

you can create your client_id here:

https://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the `access_token` at all. Just register your application with Instagram, get the `client_id` and use that to query.

To quote the [documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/):

> Note that in many situations, you may not need to authenticate users
>   at all. For instance, **you may request popular photos without
>   authenticating (i.e. you do not need to provide an access_token; just
>   use your client ID with your request)**. We only require authentication
>   in cases where your application is making requests on behalf of a user
>   (commenting, liking, browsing a user’s feed, etc.).

Comment: Sadly, this is outdated now. After the 2016 change at insta.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get the image from your Instagram account:

```
$clientId = 'Added-your-client_id';

$set_scope_your_app = "https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=$clientId&redirect_uri=Added-your-redirect_uri&response_type=code&scope=public_content";

$get_access_token = "https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=$clientId&redirect_uri=Added-your-redirect_uri&response_type=token";

$url="https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=$get_access_token";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json);

$images = array();
foreach ($data->data as $user_data) {
    $images[] = (array) $user_data->images;
}

$standard = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['standard_resolution']->url;
}, $images);

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($standard);    
echo "<pre>";
print_r($standard);
```

I have give Referece to [Get User Media or Image in Your Instagram Example](http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2016/12/get-user-media-or-image-in-your-instagram-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to get data

1) client side - you need to give client_id

2) server side - you need to give access_token

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/#{instagram_id}/media/recent/?access_token=#{@token}"
```

this will give you the recent uploaded photo of that user whose instagram_id is given...