# C#- ASP.NET - How to get images from Instagram without API Access Token

Tags: c#, asp.net, instagram

Can I get images from Instagram  public profile without Instagram API or Access token? (only use username)

Comment: Please consider searching your question first. This question already have been answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106318/instagram-api-user-photos. Also use tags accordingly : this is not related to `c#` or `asp.net`

Answer (score 0):

The only pictures you can get from any public facing page on a Facebook service are profile pictures of public facebook pages (i.e. http://graph.facebook.com/honda/picture) otherwise you have to have a developer account and you have to go through the App Review process.